# p:dataExporter not exporting headers of p:columnGroup

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I'm using p:columngroup in tag. The header and values are displayed in the webpage, but not exported to excel. Values are being exported correctly to excel, but the header row is blank after export.

**Below is XHTML code:**

```
<ui:composition template="../templates/pwpMenuLayoutTemplate.xhtml"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
    xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
    xmlns:jc="http://jcoe.ford.com/jsfcore"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">
    <f:metadata>
        <jc:preRenderView bean="#{profileCreationBean}" pageTitle="" />
    </f:metadata>
    <ui:define name="windowTitle">#{bundle['label.menu.attendance.summary.clockinout']}</ui:define>
    <h:head>
    <h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="styles.app.css"  />     
    </h:head>
    <ui:define name="content">
        <h:form id="asmReportForm"  prependId="false">
            <h1><h:outputFormat style="font-family: AntennaCond" value="#{bundle['label.menu.attendance.summary.clockinout']}">
            </h:outputFormat></h1>
            <p:messages id="messages" globalOnly="true" />
                      <h:commandLink
                            value="#{bundle['lable.dataExporter.exportExcel']}"
                            styleClass="excel-link" width="50" height="50">
                            <p:dataExporter target="clockinoutid" type="xls"
                                fileName="ClockinOutReport">
                            </p:dataExporter>
                      </h:commandLink>          

                <p:dataTable var="emp" id="clockinoutid" value="#{clockinOutReportBean.listEmpBO1}" >                   

                        <p:columnGroup type="header">
                        <p:row>
                        <p:column style="width:50px" rowspan="2">
                              <f:facet name="header">
                                 <h:outputText value="GPID" />
                            </f:facet>
                        </p:column>
                        <p:column style="width:100px" rowspan="2">
                         <f:facet name="header">
                                 <h:outputText value="Name" />
                            </f:facet>
                        </p:column>
                        <p:column style="width:50px" rowspan="2" >
                         <f:facet name="header">
                                 <h:outputText value="CDSID" />
                            </f:facet>
                        </p:column>
                        <p:column style="width:50px" rowspan="2" >
                        <f:facet name="header">
                                 <h:outputText value="Designation" />
                            </f:facet>
                         </p:column>
                        <c:forEach items="#{clockinOutReportBean.dates}" var="id">
                            <p:column style="width:100px" colspan="2" >
                            <f:facet name="header">
                                 <h:outputText value="#{id}" />
                            </f:facet>
                            </p:column>
                        </c:forEach>
                        <p:column style="width:50px" rowspan="2">
                        <f:facet name="header">
                                 <h:outputText value="Team Leader" />
                            </f:facet>
                        </p:column>
                        <p:column style="width:50px" rowspan="2">
                        <f:facet name="header">
                                 <h:outputText value="Process Coach" />
                            </f:facet>
                        </p:column>
                        <p:column style="width:50px" rowspan="2">
                            <f:facet name="header">
                                 <h:outputText value="Team Manager" />
                            </f:facet>
                         </p:column>
                        <p:column style="width:50px" rowspan="2" >
                        <f:facet name="header">
                                 <h:outputText value="Area Manager" />
                            </f:facet>
                        </p:column>
                        <p:column style="width:150px" colspan = "#{clockinOutReportBean.leavecount}">
                        <f:facet name="header">
                                 <h:outputText value="Leaves" />
                            </f:facet>
                        </p:column>
                        </p:row>

                        <p:row>
                            <c:forEach items="#{clockinOutReportBean.dates}" var="id">
                                <p:column style="width:25px" rowspan="1" >
                                <f:facet name="header">
                                 <h:outputText value="In" />
                            </f:facet>
                            </p:column>
                                <p:column style="width:25px" rowspan="1" >
                                <f:facet name="header">
                                 <h:outputText value="Out" />
                            </f:facet>
                            </p:column>
                            </c:forEach>
                            <c:forEach items="#{clockinOutReportBean.leaveNames}" var="id">
                                <p:column style="width:25px" rowspan="1" >
                                <f:facet name="header">
                                 <h:outputText value="#{id}" />
                            </f:facet>
                            </p:column>
                            </c:forEach>
                         </p:row>

                        </p:columnGroup>


                        <p:column>
                              <h:outputText value="#{emp.gpid}" />
                        </p:column>

                        <p:column>
                                 <h:outputText value="#{emp.name}" />
                        </p:column>

                        <p:column>
                                 <h:outputText value="#{emp.cdsid}" />
                         </p:column>

                        <p:column>
                                 <h:outputText value="#{emp.empPositionTitle}" />
                         </p:column> 

                         <c:forEach items="#{clockinOutReportBean.dates}" var="id">
                            <p:column>
                                <h:outputText value="#{emp.swipelist[id].swipeinTime}" />
                            </p:column>
                            <p:column>
                                <h:outputText value="#{emp.swipelist[id].swipeoutTime}" />
                            </p:column>
                        </c:forEach>

                         <p:column>
                                 <h:outputText value="#{emp.teamLeader}" />
                         </p:column> 

                         <p:column>
                                 <h:outputText value="#{emp.processCoach}" />
                         </p:column> 

                         <p:column>
                                 <h:outputText value="#{emp.teamManager}" />
                         </p:column> 

                         <p:column>
                                 <h:outputText value="#{emp.areaManager}" />
                         </p:column> 

                        <p:columns var="id" value="#{clockinOutReportBean.leaveNames}">
                                <h:outputText value="#{emp.leaveList[id].value}" />
                        </p:columns>

                    </p:dataTable>      


        </h:form>
    </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

All the data are exporting correctly. But header is not visible in excel. Can someone please help?

Comment: Welcome to `StackOverflow`, please don't just copy & paste your whole code. Create a [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) instead.

Comment: When you create a [mcve] you probably will run into the problem as headers are exported on https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/dataexporter/basic.xhtml

Comment: I tried n number of times to work on this. But headers are not getting exported

Comment: Are they getting exported when you are **not** using a columngroup?

Comment: Yes.. they are getting exported

Comment: If you know [Apache POI](https://poi.apache.org/), I think its better you create your own workbook by uisng `postProcessor` attribute of `p:dataExporter` tag. So you will have more control with the view and data of workbook.

Comment: https://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=37582

Answer (score 1):

A workaround is add columns with `style="display: none;"` to avoid duplicate it on screen, but for exporting, while columnGroup are not shown, those ones with `display: none` are.

Answer (score 0):

You can fix this with adding another `headerText` attribute to your columns in your dataarea. You will have the same attribute in your header section and in your data section.

Looks like this:

```
<p:dataTable .. >
  <p:columnGroup type="header"> 
     <p:row>
     <p:column style="width:50px" rowspan="2">
         <f:facet name="header">
              <h:outputText value="GPID" />
          </f:facet>
      </p:column>
    ......
  </p:columnGroup>
  <!-- Data area -->
  <p:column headerText="GPID">
    <h:outputText value="#{emp.gpid}" />
  </p:column>
```

Answer (score -1):

If you know [Apache POI](https://poi.apache.org/) for custom layout of the workbook, which are not provided by default `p:dataExporter` can use `postProcessor` attribute.

```
<p:dataExporter postProcessor="#{backendBean.postProcessXLS}" type="xls" target="tableId" fileName="x"  />
```

and then add this `postProcessXLS` method in following way to the back-end bean.

```
 public void postProcessXLS(Object document) {
    HSSFWorkbook wb = (HSSFWorkbook) document;
    HSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);
    // TO-DO: change layout of the sheet or add or remove any sheet to workbook
 }
```

Comment: This is unfortunately not a solution for the problem above if I'm not mistaken since that is something that should (=can only) be done **during** processing, not before or afterwards via pre- or postprocessing

Comment: Yes. It’s an alternative. As by dafault dataexporter doesn’t provide custom template or columns for xls.

Comment: But how do you add headers to the sheet in post-processing if they were not already there in the first place? I know you can change all sorts of look and feel afterwards, but do you have access to the original datatable to add the missing headers from there? Your 'comment' in the code does not provide any hints and that part is the most crucial one

Comment: I removed the sheet and recreated it.

Comment: So effectively you created your own exporter? You fully 'parsed' the datatable again and added everything, including headers for columngroups? Why not simply override (extend) the basic exporter. Way easier in my opinion. If you instead think your solution is simpler, please show what you did to get the columngroup headers and if it is simpler you'll get my upvote (and a bonus)

Comment: Yes I agree with u. Overriding the exporter classes would be more performance oriented. For my scenario datatable data was only loaded once from database without lazy pagination. And removing and recreating sheet didn’t kill much performance for me. This a just a alternative to quickly solve the problem which comes with performance drawback if the datatable has lazyloading pagination and all.

Comment: I'm not talking about performance, I'm talking about simplicity of implementation.